# Resolution of MUSIC algorithm

Tags: estimation, superresolution

MUSIC algorithm has been known to provide super-resolution imaging capabilities, and it is implemented in target recognition radar system, however, I couldn't find a definite expression for its resolution (minimum spacing between two components).

is there a known expression for the resolution improvement provided by MUSIC algorithm over -for example- the FFT method?

Comment: Good question!  Do you have a specific definition of resolution?

Comment: MUSIC frequency estimation algorithm relies on the separation of eigenvalues and eigenvectors of the auto-correlation matrix R of the noisy input signal x into noise and signal types from which noise and signal subspaces are defined. And computes the frequency estimates based on the orthogonality of those two subspaces. Resolution depends on how accurately those eigenvectors are computed and that further depends on the effect of noise on the accuracy of autocorrelation matrix estimation...

Comment: @PeterK. If MUSIC is used in frequency estimation, the resolution will be defined as the spectral resolution, or simply the peak width.